# Prevent indexing of sub-directories of parent domain

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Say my site children.com ( which I want indexed ) is also accessible via http://mother.com/children/ ( which I don't want indexed ).

Example hierarchy: 
/home/username/mother : http://mother.com
|_ children : http://www.children.com

What would I put in my mother.com/robots.txt file to prevent content in children.com and all sub-directories of children.com from being indexed as belonging to mother.com?

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my own question and confirmed it via a phpwebby robots.txt analyzer... I've put the following  code into mother.com/robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow: /
User-agent: Adsbot-Google
Disallow: /
User-agent: Jeeves
Disallow: /
User-agent: Slurp
Disallow: /
User-agent: Yahoo-MMCrawler
Disallow: /
User-agent: msnbot
Disallow: /
User-agent: psbot
Disallow: /
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

And added the following to my chilren.com robots.txt file.

```
User-agent: *
#block indexing of email and print pages -------
Disallow: /*~email.shtml
Disallow: /*~print.shtml
Sitemap: http://www.children.com/sitemap_index.xml
```

Of course I triple checked to make sure ( using the robots.txt file analyzer ) that various subdirectories were NOT accessible via the mother.com domain and that they WERE indexable via the children.com domain.

Note: Just using the mother.com and children.com domains as examples.

Answer (score 0):

You actually probably don't even want to use robots.txt. But instead use a combination of the [robots meta tag](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/03/using-robots-meta-tag.html) and [canonical tags](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394).

On all the mother.com/children pages, add the meta robots tag with a value of "noindex". Although the search engine will be able to crawl the page, it won't add these pages to the index. Now, this can still create some confusion as to the authoritative location of the content.

So you'll want to use a cross domain canonical tag to inform the major search engines where the authoritative content lives. So you'll add a canonical tag on the pages of mother.com/children and give them values on children.com. You'll want to make sure that if it's a specific page, you canonicalize it to the same content on children.com, because the canonical tag is really only meant for identical content.